# Include paths not working as expected for folder structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to VS Code and setting up my C++ project at the moment. I am using the Boost libraries and expecting some issues with configuring the include paths within the configuration file *c_cpp_properties.json*.

My configuration file:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/shared",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/winrt",
            "D:/SVN/kWorld/kWorld/src",
            "D:/Programme/boost_1_64_0"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/shared",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/winrt"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
]
```

}

However VS Code still gives me the *include file not found in include path* warning for the directive

```
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
```

I assume the problem is that the included header is not located directly in one of the referenced directories but in a lower directory. However the include directive has the full path relative to *D:/Programme/boost_1_64_0*

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost headers are probably located in `D:/Programme/boost_1_64_0/include/boost-1-64/` or similar
And the libraries should be in `D:/Programme/boost_1_64_0/lib/`.

Try including with the full path to a folder that should contain a boost folder containing the headers files.

Comment: In my Boost distribution the header files are in the folder *D:\Programme\boost_1_64_0\boost*. That's why I have to use the include directive as shown in my question.

I am afraid that VS Code would not be so useful if one had to add every single folder containing header files to the include path separately. I am sure that VS Code does recursive search within the include paths but I can not find people with similar problems.

Comment: No it is not recursive, you are explicitely specifying the path in your include directive. All it does is try to resolve against the PATH variable in your environnement and your configuration. Do you have autocompletion on the function included from this file ? Because the build configuration for VS code is in `tasks.json`

Comment: Too bad.

Since Boosts source file are organised in a structure with many, many folders, do I really have to specify each of the folders on my include path to use auto completion while coding? I don't want to use VS Code for building, just for coding.